# AWS: Access Denied when trying to load presigned url (direct fileupload browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm attempting to use a presigned URL but I keep getting a `403 Forbidden Access Denied`  despite setting up everything as I believe that I'm supposed to. I want to upload a file directly from the browser to Amazon S3.

I'm first of all enabling the root AWS account to use `putObject`. I don't have any additional accounts - I just want it to work for my root account to begin with. Here is the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "XXXX",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "XXXXX",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXX/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my Node.js backend. Here I just generate the url and send it to the frontend. Some code for the backend:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.update({
  region: "eu-north-1",
  accessKeyId: "XXX",
  secretAccessKey: "YYY"
});

const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01" });

app.get('/geturl', (req,res) => {

   const s3Params = {
      Bucket: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      Key: req.query.filename,
      Expires: 500,
      ContentType: req.query.type,
      ACL: "public-read"
   };

   s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", s3Params, (err, data) => {
      res.send(data);
   });

})
```

In the frontend, i make a simple call using the URL with the file I wish to upload. When I perform the second fetch call, it will generate the error:

```
async function handleUpload(e) {
     const file = e.target.files[0];

     const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/geturl');

     const url  = await res.text();

     const resUpload = await fetch(url, { method: 'PUT', body: file });


}
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

**Edit - Seems like it works if I uncheck the first checkbox - is this a big deal or should this always be blocked in a production env?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your backend try changing `ACL: "public-read"` to `ACL: "private"`. You should then be able to block all public access and still be able to successfully complete presigned puts/posts.